# How can time to sort an array dramatically change in Java according to Gap Size?

Tags: java, sorting, big-o

I basically create 10 random arrays from sizes: 
8000,16000,32000,64000,128000,256000

What I mean is I have 10 arrays of size 8000, 10 arrays of size 16000, etc..

These are all populated with random numbers ranging from 0 to array size.

I have an implementation for shell sort:

```
public static void sortMyArray(int[] a){
for (int gap = a.length / 2; gap > 0; gap = (gap / 2)) {
    for (int i = gap; i < a.length; i++) {
        int tmp = a[i];
        int j = i;
        for (; j >= gap && tmp < (a[j - gap]); j -= gap) {
            a[j] = a[j - gap];
        }
        a[j] = tmp;
     }
}
}
```

When the gap is gap = a.length / a. length I simply have an insertion sort. Here are the times to sort these arrays:

```
Number of Elements  Milliseconds
8000                13
16000               53
32000               217
64000               828
128000              3311
256000              13352
```

So this is roughly O(N^2). When number of elements double, time to solve increases by almost 4 times.

However, when I use gap = a.length / 2 I get values like:

```
Number of Elements  Milliseconds
8000                2
16000               2
32000               4
64000               10
128000              25
256000              60
```

So this is even better than O(N) I guess?
How is this possible? I tried shutting down processors from Windows, and I tried running the computer only on 1 processor, however the values were still not logical.

Here is my full code if you are interested:

```
int[] arraySizes = new int[]{8000,16000,32000,64000,128000,256000};
Random rn = new Random(1);

for(int i=0;i<arraySizes.length;i++){
    int[] arrayToBeSorted = new int[arraySizes[i]];
    System.out.println("Solving array with: " + arraySizes[i] + " elements with first sorting algorithm.");
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        for(int t=0;t<arraySizes[i];t++){
            int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(arrayToBeSorted.length);
            arrayToBeSorted[t] = randomNumber;
        }
        Long initialTime = (new Date().getTime());
        sortMyArray(arrayToBeSorted);
        Long finalTime = (new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println("Time in milliseconds:" + (finalTime - initialTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Random rn = new Random(1); this seems suspect. just use default Random rn = new Random(); or put a large  random seed like Random rn = new Random(730495);

Comment: How does the seed effect, why is it suspicious?

Comment: i do not know enough about random generators but the seed is important is what i read. I made a sample app but for me the time does not change -> Solving array with: 256000 elements with first sorting algorithm.
Time in milliseconds:213 (always get 207 to 223) for gap = a.length and gap = a.length /  2

Comment: Note that using a fixed seed causes the result to bias towards the sequence of numbers generated by the seed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your implementations seem to be correct your assumption is not.

You assume that if a function has an O(n^2) complexity and a running time of 3311 seconds then some other function with a complexity of O(n) should run about 57 seconds on the same data.

However big O notation gives an idea about the grow rate of the function not the actual running time. Therefore you can't just compare running times of different functions according to their grow rates.

Comment: Hello, What I want to say is that, in Insertion Sort when the array size grows by a multiple of 2, running time grows by a degree of 4. So  running time depends on the square of number of elements in the array. However, when gap size equals 2, when number of elements in the array doubles, running time also doubles accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "when gap size equals 2"?

Comment: Sorry, a.length / 2 I mean. Gap size equals half of array.. In shear sort situation.

Comment: This is not correct: "when number of elements in the array doubles, running time also doubles accordingly". 60/25 = 2.4, 25/10 = 2.5 etc..